# SQL UPDATE event not working correctly with discord.js via message event

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, npm, discord.js

I've been trying over the past days to get an SQL UPDATE event to work correctly with discord.js using the mysql npm package. All the login details and table, column names are correct. This is meant to update the integer every time a message is sent in the Discord text channel.

I have tried multiple types of the UPDATE even none of which have worked out.

See these logging screenshots:
- https://faxes.zone/img/y4fx1.png (Before / after the event was triggered)
- https://faxes.zone/img/8610v.png (discord.js console when a message is sent)

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
    if ( message.channel.type === 'dm' ) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(".")) return;

    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, function (err, resultLogs) {
        if(err) throw err;
        let sql;

        if(resultLogs[0]) {
            console.log(resultLogs[0].msgcount)
            let newMessageCount = resultLogs[0].msgcount++;
            sql = `UPDATE logs SET msgcount = ${newMessageCount} WHERE id=${message.author.id}`
            connection.query(sql, console.log)
        }
    });  
});
```

The expected output should be the integer increasing by one every time a message is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment the `msgcount` with a MySql operator. So you don't need to make a select query. And also you need to escape the value in the sql statement to prevent injections.

Btw, I refactored your code.

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if ( message.channel.type === 'dm' || message.author.bot || message.content.startsWith(".") ) return;

    connection.query('UPDATE logs SET msgcount = msgcount + 1 WHERE id = ?', [message.author.id], (error,  result) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      
      console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used discord JS but your code logic seems correct to me, although some parts seem weird to me :

```
sql = `UPDATE logs SET msgcount = ${newMessageCount} WHERE id=${message.author.id}`
        connection.query(sql, console.log)
```

why does this part do not have a semi colon after each lines ?

Also i forgot the behavior of the ` symbol with strings, but are you sure the sql query is correct (like the message count and id value are correctly replacing the variables) ? Try printing it to see

(for the 'select' query, you used apostrophes)

Comment: Yeah ` works as strings for SQL. If I print the SELECT query it prints out so it is definitely grabbing the information correctly.

Comment: What about the UPDATE query ?
Lets say your id is "544" and old messag count is '7'
Does it print as 

"UPDATE logs SET msgcount = 8 WHERE id = 544 "  ?

If so then i dont see the error